# ROCm and CUDA GPUs on one model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, amd-rocm

I want to compile a model on multiple GPU's. Is it possible to use AMD GPUs with ROCm together with Nvidia CUDA GPUs on the same model?
I guess it's not possible since you need to install a special version of tensorflow in order to enable ROCm tensorflow?